# node.js promises error underfined function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

MY issue is parse large xml file (with xml2js), and forEach element in cycle(product) , download image and save it to file.
I wrote this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var baseUrl = 'http://shop.nag.ru/uploads/catalog_item_image_main/';
var async = require('async');
var processImg = require('./downloader');
var q = require('q');

var readFileSync  = function (){
    var xml = fs.readFileSync("./test.xml", "utf8");
    return xml;
};

readFileSync.then(function(xml) {
            parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
                if(err)return error;
                return result.product_list.product;
            })
    })
    .then(function(products){
        products.forEach(function(prdt) {

        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

But after run I got this error :

```
readFileSync.then(function(xml) {
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\WorkVrp\nodeImageParser\processing.js:19:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: `readFileSync` returns a value and not a promise, you're returning from `parseString` which doesn't make sense since it takes a callback (vs returns a promise). Look into how to convert callback APIs to promises.

Comment: `readFileSync` does return the file contents, not a promise?!

Comment: Why are you importing `async` and `q`, but using neither?

Comment: Maybe you can help me with, how I can use promises with  readFile async implementation

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack: see [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mistaking [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) for `fs.readFileAsync`. The former is an in-built function of [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) which returns the data directly. The latter is a function *created by* [**promisification** by Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyallobject-target--object-options---object) which returns a promise.

Here's how differently they'd be used:

**fs.readFileSync**:

```
var fs = require('fs');

try {
    var data = fs.readFileSync('./file.xml', 'utf8');
    // do something with data
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

**fs.readFileAsync**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

fs.readFileSyncAsync('./file.xml', 'utf8')
.then(function(data){
    //do something with data
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

Notice the `require('bluebird')` and `Promise.promisifyAll(fs)` which are required to actually create `fs.readFileSyncAsync` which otherwise wouldn't have been available on `fs`

With that hopefully cleared, here's how I think you'd want to re-write your code:

Some changes I think you need are:

1. You don't actually need the function `readFile`, you can just use `fs.readFileAsync` directly.
2. Your `parseString` which comes from `require('xml2js')` would be better if you just promisified `xml2js` itself like `fs` and used `xml2js.parseStringAsync`

I've also gone ahead and taken the code from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094453/node-js-callback-hell-with-files-downloader) which presumably be more helpful in you understanding the whole picture:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);
Promise.promisifyAll(request);
Promise.promisifyAll(xml2js);

var baseUrl = 'http://test.com/uploads/catalog_item_image_main/';
var processImg = require('./downloader');
var processImgAsync = Promise.promisify(processImg);

fs.readFileAsync("./test.xml", "utf8")
.then(xml2js.parseStringAsync)
.then(parseProductsAsync) // defined below
.then(processProductsAsync)
.then(function(){
    console.log('All prdt have been processed successfully');
})
.catch(console.error);


function parseProductsAsync(xmljsonresult){
    return xmljsonresult.product_list.product;
}

function processProductsAsync(products){
    return Promise.all(products.map(function(product){
        console.log('Processing file ' + product.sku);
        var filename = product.sku + "";
        filename = filename.replace(/\//g, '_');
        return processImgAsync(baseUrl + filename + '_big.', filename);
    }));
}
```

Comment: thx for help. But when I run my code with yours help, I got  all 360 messages with console.log('Processing file ' + product.sku);  and only after that I saw file downloaded message. Why I didnt see one messages with 'Processing file... + product.sku' and '..file downloaded' and etc, So its seems to me my code still not working in order.  And message  console.log('All prdt have been processed successfully'); not displayed, the program freeze on http://test.com/uploads/catalog_item_image_main/EWS7928FP_big.png - downloaded

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFileSync` returns an end value (either string or a buffer). It SYNCHRONOUS. There is no promise involved in your code, and so you get the `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

readFileSync does not return a promise, the way to use it is

value = readFileSync(filename, options);

value will be either a string or buffer, depending on encoding option

see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options

Comment: So if I use fs.readFile instead , what I need to change im my code?